# fastclick still has 300ms delay on ipad

Tags: fastclick.js

I have an angular app with fastclick so that it will respond quickly on tablets.  With iOS8, we were seeing a delay on clicking so I hooked up the iPad Mini to the Safari develop tools and was seeing the 300ms delay between the Touch End Event and the Click Event Dispatched.  I went to create a jsfiddle to test it without the rest of my app and found this one already created:

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/zrMxL/

```
new FastClick($("#fast")[0]);
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function EditingPageCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.radioModelA = undefined;
    $scope.radioModelB = undefined;
    $scope.fast1 = "this field works quickly, because of fastclick...";
    $scope.fast2 = "this field is slow, because no fastclick";
    $scope.$watch('radioModelA', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        //alert(newValue);    
    });
}
```

I hooked that one up to Safari Developer tools also and still see the 300ms delay.  Is this jsfiddle demonstrating a correct use of fastclick and if so, is there a reason that it still has the delay?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Angular-style, but try adding this top the top your script.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);
```

This worked for me in an Angular app.

Comment: Thanks for the note - yes, our app uses this approach already.  I ended up removing jquery and that helped as we had some issues with both angular and jquery.  Also, in using Yosemite with Safari Debug attached to a iOS 8 device, the device responds much slower than when it isn't attached.